# Accessing wifi through webpage

Tags: html, jsp, networking, router

So I have a router and a laptop. And I want to know if I can connect to my wifi through a web browser(jsp/php/html page). So is it possible to display a list of wifi connections and connect to that router provided I can get the name and password?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the Mac, open terminal and do:

```
 sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/sbin/airport
```

Then, to see all available connections:

```
airport -s
```

That will output quickly all relevant wifi connection info.

Comment: Any such solution available for Ubuntu?